# how to remove the header warning

Tags: php, header-files

my code is suppose to jump to the next page after the upload was successful but i've got this warning. 
'

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\XAMP\xampp\htdocs\gallery\uploader3.php:25) in C:\XAMP\xampp\htdocs\gallery\uploader3.php on line 51

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample1  - File Upload on Directory </title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form action="uploader3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
        Create an Album (limited to 10 images): <br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"   />
</form>
</div>

<?php 
$target_path = "uploads1/";
if(!file_exists($target_path))
{
    if(!mkdir($target_path))
    {
        die ("could not create the folder");
    }
}
else
{
    for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']); $count++)
        {
            $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]); 

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $target_path)) 
            {
                /*echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]). 
            " has been uploaded";*/
            } 
            else
            {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
            }
        }
}
header('Location: index.html');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I solve this? Thanks AHEAD! :D

Comment: please dont vote down on my post.. im new in php.. :(

Comment: You... need to rethink the flow of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code flow is wrong. Your php script is being executed as soon as that page loads, not when the user submits the form

You need to move the code thats between `<?php ?>` (including those tags) to uploader3.php as thats where your forms target action is set to.

Alternatively you can put the script at the top of the page and check that form data has been sent, and remove the action attribute from the form tag so that it just submits back to itself or change it so it points back to itself

Example

```
<?php 

//Check that you have some post data
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $target_path = "uploads1/";
    if(!file_exists($target_path))
    {
        if(!mkdir($target_path))
        {
            die ("could not create the folder");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']); $count++)
            {
                $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]); 

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $target_path)) 
                {
                    /*echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]). 
                " has been uploaded";*/
                } 
                else
                {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
                }
            }
    }
    header('Location: index.html');

}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Sample1  - File Upload on Directory </title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
        Create an Album (limited to 10 images): <br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File"   />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

TIPS:

- write [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the top of the page
- write `exit()` just after `header()`

Comment: OB won't fix the fundamental architectural flaws in the code.

Comment: thats why i said it `TIPS` not `solution`

Comment: Why answer with something that isn't a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that some function that sends header (a `header('location')`, `session_start`, etc) cannot do so, because it is allready send.

Most of the time this is because you implicitly send headers if you start outputting stuff. Common mistakes are

- whitespace in front ofyour opening tag: this is output, so gets send (with headers)
- A bunch of HTML before you start your PHP (like `session_start`)

Just find the line the warning talks about, check out what function is called, and make sure you want that function there, and if it sends headers, make sure you don't send stuff before.

Now you can, as @diEcho suggest, use output buffering to fix this, but I don't think you'd want this in all cases. (I'd sooner think most cases don't need it).

Answer (score -1):

Write `OB_START` at the beginning. This will remove the warning but your code is not proper to redirect on second page.

Comment: this would actually give the end user a blank page, never showing the form itself if put at the beginning as there is nothing being put to the browser